# Does Texture aka AsyncDisplayKit support PHLivePhotoView?

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I am trying to integrate **Live Photos** into my iOS app and can't seem to figure out how to integrate Live Photos while using Texture. Is there a way to integrate Live Photos with Texture? For instance, an `ASImageNode` or `ASNetworkImageNode` is used in place of a `UIImageView`, `ASVideoNode` for video etc.

If Texture doesn't support `PHLivePhotoView` is there another solution I can implement while still using Texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's way to do this, by wrapping your `PHLivePhotoView`.
as long as your `customView` inheriting `UIView`, you make use this

```
let node = ASDisplayNode { () -> UIView in
        // return your `UIView` here
    }
```

*Happy Texturing*